# Quitting internship for a full time job

Tags: job-offer, new-job, internship

Currently I am interning at small scale software company. I joined that internship as per my university course work. I will be getting a grade based on that. Actually the internship is of 6 months and I will complete my course work from university side by the end of 5th month. I currently have a job opportunity from the start of 6th month.

Now the problem is how can I quit my internship at the end of 5th month.

In addition I will get a certificate of completion too at the end of fifth month which is need to be submitted in the university to give presentation on my work.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the sixth month of the internship required to get your degree?

Comment: Is the sixth month of the internship required to get your degree?                                                  Its not compulsory from the university side. My presentation and evaluation will be completed by the end of fifth month.

Comment: I was in a similar situation, I contacted both my manager and the dean academics affair of my university well in advance, informed them both of the situation, they both understood and I had the option of leaving at the end of 5 month, only condition was I should properly transfer everything I was doing, but then my manager also inquired about the job offer and gave me a better one, so I am not actually leaving now, but yes people do understand, just talk to them, who knows, it might even be better for you.

Comment: @Augustus0498 The date of the presentation and evaluation is a slightly different issue from whether the sixth month of the internship is required. If it were required, the university, despite having the evaluation in hand, would not award the degree unless you complete the last month.

Comment: The sixth month is not in the part of evaluation. @Patricia Shanahan

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should check is whether there is an early separation penalty/notice period requirement in your employment contract.  It seems unlikely for an internship, but you should make sure you know.  If there is, you'll want to decide if you'd still be willing to leave a month early.  Additionally, if there is your new company might be open to having you start later or reimbursing you.

However, in the more likely case that you can terminate your internship at any time contractually, this really comes down to whether you think you should talk to your boss.  A reasonable boss will work with you to start your notice period early (or offer an incentive for you to stay for the last month) and not take this personally, maybe even congratulate you.  An unreasonable boss will take it personally and badmouth you to whoever asks.  An extremely unreasonable boss will terminate your internship early to try and mess with your academic credit.  Hopefully most bosses are the first kind, but questioners on this site seem to have a knack for finding the second and third kinds.  If you don't tell your boss until the last Friday, that will certainly burn bridges with them and the company, so you shouldn't do that unless you are very sure telling them will go poorly for you.  You could consider sending your resignation in writing to your boss and HR at the same time, just to get ahead of any possible retaliation (HR is unlikely to care about an intern leaving early, but might stop your manager from trying to fire you if they know you are already leaving).  In any case, you should try to give them a reasonable notice period, 2-3 weeks is pretty normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where communicating with everybody is important. Transparency!

To your uni, ask about leaving the internship early. Tell them your situation with a new job lined up. Can you meet your uni's expectations and get your degree if you leave early?

Once you know it's ok with the uni, talk to your present internship supervisor. Explain your job offer, and explain what you want to do.

To your new job's manager, explain you have an internship that runs for another month. Say you'll try to join them sooner, but you want to ensure you meet all your existing commitments.

And keep everybody informed when you decide what to do.

Don't worry about this. Often people coming straight from school to a job have some uncertainty about the exact date they're available. And everybody -- uni, internship, job --  wants you to succeed, so they'll help.

Comment: the university is happy to know that we got an opportunity and they have no problem in leaving company early. But the company is refusing to give certificate for the amount of time i have worked and the company I got an offer was not in a position to extend the joining date as they have huge requirement.

Comment: And the company which i am currently interning have strange rules which you cannot get in any other company. This is making me to try for other companies.